# Aggregating NPS Questions into a Single Score

Tags: survey, net-promoter-score

I've looked for the answer across this site and survey sites like MeasuringU but haven't found an answer. Any help is appreciated!

I have a multiple question survey using NPS-style questions but applying to different parts of the customer experience.

> 1. How likely is it that you would recommend this company to a friend or colleague?
> 2. How likely is it that you would recommend this store branch to a friend or colleague?
> 3. How likely is it that you would recommend your cashier to a friend or colleague?

Can I use the NPS calculation across both questions to create a single NPS? The idea is to take a ALL of the promotomer and detractors and use it to create a combined score. Mathematically or logically, why can/can't I do it?

I've seen other sites talk about [variations on NPS](https://measuringu.com/8-manipulations/), but nothing about aggregating questions.

Comment: Although you can do it, the NPS is already so crude that it would be worth seriously considering a more suitable analysis of the survey.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mathematically, what is your reasoning?

Comment: It reduces the precision by a factor of almost $3$ by condensing a 1-10 scale into a three-level scale.  When you do that to two questions you are giving up a lot of information you might otherwise be able to exploit.